# Javascript changing calc property in CSS unexpected output in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox

Expected output:

```
transform: translateX(calc(-100% / 3 * 1));
```

Chrome:

```
transform: translateX(calc(-33.3333333333333%));
```

Firefox:

```
transform: translateX(calc(-100% / 3 * 1));
```

Snippet:

```js
document.getElementById('block').style.transform = 'translateX(calc(-100% / 3 * 1))'
```

```css
#block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

It's not really a problem but I'm just curious why chrome does it this way?
Does Chrome calculate the outcome before it injects the css?
Also if you write it in your stylesheet it doesn't do this.

Comment: usually calc is used to add pixels (or ems) and percentages. why even use calc if your outcome is a percentage?

Comment: @plondon has a point. Does the same happen for a real calculation like `calc(50% - 10em + 17px)`?